# Iterate through list of lists and insert computed value into nth position

Tags: python

I need to iterate through a list of lists and insert a computed value at position [4] in each of the lists. Each sub list has 5 elements.  The computed value will be element [1] / total.  For example:

```
total = 10000
A = [xyz, 5000, .25, .12, ''], [abc, 2000, .3, .4, ''], ....
```

Result needed:

```
A = [xyz, 5000, .25, .12, .5 (ie, 5000/10000), ''], [abc, 2000, .3, .4, .2, ''], .....
```

Comment: use list.insert(i, x) on each inner list i guess https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
total = 10000
A = [['xyz', 5000, .25, .12, ''], ['abc', 2000, .3, .4, '']]

for a in A:
  a.insert(4, a[1] / total)

print(A)
```

This would return:
`[['xyz', 5000, 0.25, 0.12, 0.5, ''], ['abc', 2000, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, '']]`

Comment: thanks to both of you - both answered at the same time; If it is not a list of lists, what is it?

Answer (score 4):

```
total = 10000
A = [0, 5000, .25, .12, ''], [2, 2000, .3, .4, '']

for element in A:
    element.insert(4, element[1] / total)

print(A)
# ([0, 5000, 0.25, 0.12, 0.5, ''], [2, 2000, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, ''])
```

Comment: It's a tuple of lists, which is easy enough to change to a list of lists - just add square brackets to the definition of A